# How do I strip only time taken from default IIS log using regex selecting last occurrence of number not an IP address

Tags: regex, iis, regular-language

I'm trying to strip just the time taken number which in my example is 95 before the 10.0.0.0 ip address in the message. Sometimes the message has the last IP and sometimes it doesn't I need to select 95 in all cases. I tried to do a numerical look forward like I did for selecting the last IP but it doesn't behave as expected.

Example Log Message:

```
2019-04-15 19:48:21 2.2.2.2 POST /Communication/Service.svc - 8604 - 1.1.1.1 - - 200 0 0 95 10.0.0.0
```

Any help on how to do this with regex would be greatly appreciated.

This is what I've tried:

`enter code here`( \d+)(?!\d+)

however this selects the following:

[image]

How do I select just time taken?

Comment: Can you use a capturing group? https://regex101.com/r/rCLf1a/1/

Comment: Regex does not strip or remove anything, it only matches strings. Removing is done with some programming language, what is yours? In some very specific cases, parts before and after are captured and then joined, like `^(.*?)\s+\d+(\s+\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})?$` and then Group 1 + Group 2 will create the expected result. But where are you using the regex?

Comment: If you want to use a lookahead and get only the match instead of a group try `(?<!\S)\d+(?=(?: \d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})?$)` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DeiXom/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Kibana Scripted Fields

Comment: @Thefourthbird your (?<!\S)\d+(?=(?: \d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})?$) worked. Thanks

Comment: @GrantZukel You are welcome. I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a negative lookbehind asserting what is directly on the left is not a non whitespace character.

For the ip number you might choose to use an ip like format. Note that it can match more than an ip range. If you want a more exact match, [this page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html) might be helpful.

```
(?<!\S)\d+(?=(?: \d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})?$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DeiXom/1)

- `(?<!\S)` negative lookbehind, assert what is directly on the left is not a non whitespace char
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is

  - `(?: \d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})?` Optionally match a space, 1-3 digits and repeat 3 times matching a dot and 1-3 digits
- `$`Assert end of the string
- `)` Close positive lookahead